# Lapis not using values from config.moon

Tags: nginx, openresty, moonscript, lapis

I'm following the guides on [leafo.net/lapis](http://leafo.net/lapis/reference/configuration.html) to create a configuration file. My `config.moon` is in the top level folder of the app and looks like this

```
config = require "lapis.config"

config "development", ->
  port 5001
```

When I run `lapis build` or `lapis server`, I can see that the datestamp on my `nginx.conf.compiled` has changed, but it appears to have ignored my configuration, as it's still listening on port 8080

```
  server {
    listen 8080;
    lua_code_cache off;
```

`lapis server` will therefore attempt to connect at that port and fail. What have I missed?

App structure:

```
.. (up a dir)
/home/sam/lapis-example/
▸ client_body_temp/
▸ fastcgi_temp/
▸ logs/
▸ proxy_temp/
▸ scgi_temp/
▸ uwsgi_temp/
  app.moon
  config.moon
  mime.types
  models.moon
  nginx.conf
  nginx.conf.compiled
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to compile your `.moon` files to `.lua` in order for the Lapis command line tool to read them. The command line tools do not know how to load `.moon` files on their own.

You can do this using the `moonc` command, run this in the top level directory:

```
moonc .
```

You can have it automatically compile using the watch command:

```
moonc -w .
```

Comment: Thank you, that should have been obvious in hindsight but I'm brand new to all of it. Great stuff!